# Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::current()

Tags: php, mongodb

I get in PHP this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::current()`.
```

Which seems to be in contradiction with [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php).

I can show my code but, well, I call the method `current()` for a MongoDB cursor.

Comment: What is your mongodb version (just in case)?

Comment: my version is 4.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality was just added a few weeks ago:

> MongoDB\Driver\Cursor has historically only implemented Traversable and provided an internal iterator (not to be to the Iterator userland class). PHP 8 required that we implement either Iterator or IteratorAggregate directly (PHPC-1690), although PHP also provides an internal iterator for extensions to make that easier.

> That said, we should consider providing a proper Iterator implementation on the Cursor to remove our reliance on the internal iterator class for PHP 8 and present a consistent API for all supported versions.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-1691 (Resolved 4 November 2020)

Ensure any packages you have are up-to-date, or [install from source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/master/src) if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check an installation of your MongoDB PHP Driver
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

Comment: Thanks but I've gone for Typescript long ago